# What will change with my new Inverter?

Tags: battery-life, ups

Before i had a 750W Inverter (12V input) and i use 2 x 12V (150AH) car batteries connected in Parallel.

With this configuration , i can keep my 2 Computers around 2 hours when there's no electricity.

Now my old Inverter is broken , so i've decided to buy another inverter. But this new inverter requires 24V Input voltage. So according to inverter's manual i should connect the 2 batteries in Series.

My question is :

With this new configuration , will i be able to keep again my Computers for the same time (2 hours) when no electricity or this new batterie's configuration will decrease this time ?

Thank you !

Comment: Theoretically, yes, but it depends whether the efficiency has increased or decreased. Connecting them in parallel or series does not change the total energy (Watt Hours) of the bank.

Comment: @Josh Jobin I was confused by this article , http://www.mpptsolar.com/en/batteries-series-parallel.html where i've read that 2x12V batteries (200AH) in parallel = 400AH , instead of 2x12V batteries (200AH) in series = 200AH.?!!

Comment: I understand your confusion. I am not entirely sure why we use AH as an energy rating when WH seems to be less confusing. If you have two 12V 200Ah batteries in parallel, your system voltage is 12V with 400Ah which is 12V*400Ah=4800Wh. If you take two 12V 200Ah batteries and put them in series you get a system voltage of 24V with a 200Ah bank which is 24V*200Ah=4800Wh. Both have exactly the same joules of energy but different Ah ratings. (1 Watt Hour = 3600 Joules)

Comment: @Ferdi Your 2 batteries should give 150Ah x 12V x 2 = 3600Wh (watt.hours). If they support your computers for 2 hours the load on the batteries is 1800W. If we assume your old inverter was 80% efficient then the power delivered to the load is 1800 x 0.8 = 1440W. There are 2 problems here: your old inverter was only rated for 750W, and so should not be capable of supplying 1440W. Also, do your 2 computers really take 1440W?  It sounds too much. My guess is that your batteries are old and can no longer supply 150Ah each.

Comment: Lead acid storage battery capacity is usually rated according to the 20 hour discharge rate. In other  words, a fully-charged, brand-new 150 Ah battery can deliver 7.5A for 20 hours. At the end of 20 hours, the battery Voltage will be 10V (for a 12V battery). When discharged at more than 7.5A, the capacity will be much less. Also, when discharged all the way to 10V, the cycle life of the battery will suffer. It would be better to terminate discharge at a higher Voltage, but then you get less capacity.

Comment: @ Steve G - I've said around 2 hours. But this is not important. What i'm asking is : If when i had my old inverter with batteries connected in parallel , i was able to keep them working for about 2 hours , what about now when i have another inverter with batteries connected in serial ? ( Let's assume that 2 inverters have the same specifications , except the input voltage from 12 V the old and 24V the new) , and the batteries are the same. So should i go buying this new 24V inverter , or is better to get another 12V inverter ?

Comment: @JoshJobin, I think your first comment _is_ the answer. Consider making it one?

Answer (score 1):

Just making my comments an answer:

Theoretically, yes, but it depends whether the efficiency has increased or decreased. Connecting them in parallel or series does not change the total energy (Watt Hours) of the bank.

I understand your confusion. I am not entirely sure why we use AH as an energy rating when WH seems to be less confusing. If you have two 12V 200Ah batteries in parallel, your system voltage is 12V with 400Ah which is 12V*400Ah=4800Wh. If you take two 12V 200Ah batteries and put them in series you get a system voltage of 24V with a 200Ah bank which is 24V*200Ah=4800Wh. Both have exactly the same joules of energy but different Ah ratings. (1 Watt Hour = 3600 Joules)

Comment: Ok friend , but as i haven't purchased yet the new inverter , do you think it's better to get the 24V version or a 12V version or it's the same ? ( Of course both will be connected with 2 x 12V batteries ). I'm asking for other good or bad things in my choice between the 2 versions.

Comment: Valid question, if it is indicated on the data sheet, I'd choose the inverter with the highest efficiency and lowest price. Because dollars tend to matter.

Comment: The efficency is almost equal , but the 24V version has a higher price. But  will i have any other benefits if i spend the extra money to get the 24V ?

Comment: Most likely no benefit, do you have a link for both? Maybe there are more features on the 24V inverter (if that makes sense)

Comment: Typically, all other things being equal, a 24V inverter will have a higher efficiency than a 12V inverter. The current draw will be less, which means you can use thinner power cables or have less loss in those cables.